# Get List Item details from the changelog in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, client-object-model

I am trying to manage a changelog in a Sharepoint Online custom task list with Powershell and CSOM. I can get changes in a list from the below code and retrieve details like Update type and Update time. But I want more details regarding the item that has changed. For example, the item's new value, old value, the column/row name and the user who made the change.

I searched MSDN but could not find any classes that would help me get these types of details. Existing methods that I could find through googling would parse HTML through the pages. This would not help me since I assume it would be a lot slower than CSOM and since my table is big enough and changes being made all the time, it would be inefficient to parse.
Here is the code I am working on in PowerShell:

```
Function Get-ChangeLog {
    $listName = "Tasks"
    $list = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
    $cq = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeQuery($true,$true)
    $changes = $list.GetChanges($cq)
    $clientContext.Load($changes)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    $changes.Count
    foreach ($changeItem in $changes) {
        #each item details
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ChangeItem only contains subset of fields for the actual item that was changed. You need to get the actual item using, e.g., GetItemByUniqueId, and continue with that object.

`$myRealItem = $myList.GetItemByUniqueId($changeItem.UniqueId)`